# Default namespace is not transforming correctly

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-2.0

I want to add the default name space(when transform) to the element. I used xslt for this transformation. Please find bellow code snippet.

```
<xsl:variable name="ns" select="'http://ABC.org/Standards/SChool/2'" />

<xsl:element name="School" namespace="{$ns}">
     <xsl:attribute name="Version">2.13.92</xsl:attribute>    
     <xsl:apply-templates select="ltc:UserAuthRequest" />
</xsl:element>

<xsl:template match="ltc:UserAuthRequest">
     <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
</xsl:template>
```

After the transformation I got the bellow xml output.

```
<School xmlns="http://ABC.org/Standards/SChool/2" Version="2.13.92">
     <UserAuthRequest xmlns=""></UserAuthRequest>
</School>
```

The problem here is the default namespace was created in child node also.

Can any one please explain me why the namespace was created in child element even I didnt define any namespaces for that and how to avoid this issue?

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<School>

    <UserAuth>
        <UserName>K.Senthuran</UserName>
        <Password>Javaworld</Password>
    </UserAuth>

</School>
```

**Transformation Logic**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/School">

        <xsl:variable name="ns">www.school.com/myLife</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="School" namespace="{$ns}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="UserAuth" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="UserAuth">
        <xsl:element name="UserAuth">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">sdmnsdnk</xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="UserName" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Password" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="UserName">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:attribute name="userIDREF">dmsdmsl</xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Password">

        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:attribute name="uniqueIDREF">asakjhs</xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<School xmlns="www.school.com/myLife">
    <UserAuth xmlns="" id="sdmnsdnk">
        <UserName userIDREF="dmsdmsl">K.Senthuran</UserName>
        <Password uniqueIDREF="asakjhs">Javaworld</Password>
    </UserAuth>
</School>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<School xmlns="www.school.com/myLife">
    <UserAuth id="sdmnsdnk">
        <UserName userIDREF="dmsdmsl">K.Senthuran</UserName>
        <Password uniqueIDREF="asakjhs">Javaworld</Password>
    </UserAuth>
</School>
```

Comment: Please, provide the actual XML document and the exact wanted result from the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is how to do this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNs" select="'some:NS'"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$vNs}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<School Version="2.13.92">
     <UserAuthRequest></UserAuthRequest>
</School>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<School xmlns="some:NS" Version="2.13.92">
   <UserAuthRequest/>
</School>
```

---

**Update**:

The OP clarified his question. Now, an additional requirement is to add new attributes to some elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNs" select="'some:NS'"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$vNs}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="UserAuth">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$vNs}">
   <xsl:attribute name="id">sdmnsdnk</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="UserName">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$vNs}">
   <xsl:attribute name="userIDREF">dmsdmsl</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Password">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{$vNs}">
   <xsl:attribute name="uniqueIDREF">asakjhs</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<School>
    <UserAuth>
        <UserName>K.Senthuran</UserName>
        <Password>Javaworld</Password>
    </UserAuth>
</School>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<School xmlns="some:NS">
   <UserAuth id="sdmnsdnk">
      <UserName userIDREF="dmsdmsl">K.Senthuran</UserName>
      <Password uniqueIDREF="asakjhs">Javaworld</Password>
   </UserAuth>
</School>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre for your answer. According to your approach it is working as expected. But I am doing te transformation in different way. I add some attributes and additional elements. At that time it is not working. Please suggest me.

Comment: I have a small clarification here. Why the namespace ns is not applying for other child elements even you created the namespace for child elements?

Comment: @K.Senthuran, This is "optical illusion", all elements are in the same, default namespace. This is equivalent (but more readable) to a representation where the (default) namespace of every descendant of the top element is actually shown. As per the XPath data model and the W3C Namespaces spec, all descendant element nodes "inherit" all the namespace nodes of their parent (and thus ancestors). The default namespace, as all other namespaces, is propagated to all descendants. It can be changed, suppressed only by an explicit un-declaration or declaration of another default namespace.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you create your **UserAuthRequest** you are not giving it a namespace

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}" />
```

Therefore the XSLT will generate an element with no namespace, hence the `xmlns=""`. Assuming your **ns** variable is global in scope, just create the element in the same way as you do for the **School** element

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$ns}" />
```

Actually, you don't need **local-name** here if you are matching a specific element. This would also work

```
<xsl:element name="UserAuthRequest" namespace="{$ns}" />
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your answer. Still I am facing the same issue after applying your suggestion. I think you misunderstood my problem. I don not to have any namespace in my sub elements. I mean the element UserAuthRequest or its any subelements should not have any namespace.